# How to passing external argument by call other powershell script?

Tags: powershell

I want to call another powershell script with external argument. I try this but return error. anyone can help please

```
$direct = "D:\Learn"
Start-Process powershell.exe -WindowStyle Minimized ".\Testing.exe" -Path $direct 


Testing.exe
Param(
  [parameter(mandatory=$true)][string]$Loc
)

Get-Content $Loc\API.txt
Pause
```

Comment: hey SBR, let me know if the below post helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to just run a *File* with some *arguments*

```
$filepath = ".\Testing.exe"
$direct = "D:\Learn"
Start-Process -FilePath $filepath -ArgumentList $direct -Wait -NoNewWindow
```

Comment: hi @Clint if you don't mind please check out my other question. Thank you so much
https://stackoverflow.com/q/60598457/11076819

Answer (score 2):

The [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) cmdlet has a [`-AgumentList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-7#parameters) parameter:

```
$direct = "D:\Learn"
Start-Process powershell.exe -WindowStyle Minimized ".\Testing.exe" -ArgumentList "-Path $direct"
```

Comment: it return this eror Start-Process : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '.\Testing.exe'.@Martin

Comment: Please clarify which process you want to start with which arguments

Comment: I want to start the process of Testing.exe with argument $direct

Comment: I try to change Start-Process with `&` the argument can work, but got problem, the main script can not continue to running before Testing.exe finish

Comment: Why you start powershell first? Just try this: `Start-Process".\Testing.exe" -WindowStyle Minimized -ArgumentList "-Path $direct"
`

Comment: It's not working, the Testing.exe does not execute. it return empty result

Answer (score 1):

I think they all were arguments of powershell.exe.
The whole argument can be wrapped in one double quote in argumentlist.

```
Start-Process "powershell.exe" -ArgumentList "-windowstyle minimized '.\testing.exe' -path $direct"
```

Or even it can be done without start-process:

```
& "powershell.exe -windowstyle minimized '.\testing.exe' -path $direct"
```